# Wildfly is not getting up after restart

Tags: java, sockets, jboss, timeout, wildfly

I am running wildfly 10 with jdk 8 on server. The application uses inbuilt jboss queues and stores messages in queues.  There was some error coming, and I have just directly restarted wildfly. Now I am trying to restart the wildfly but all the deployed wars are not gettig up. Getting this errors in logs.

```
2020-02-24 15:20:25,903 DEBUG [org.wildfly.iiop.openjdk] (MSC service thread 1-3) Stopping service jboss.iiop-openjdk.ior-security-config
2020-02-24 15:20:30,974 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.controller.ParallelBootOperationStepHandler$2@54f56232 for operation {"operation" => "parallel-subsystem-boot","address" => []} at address [] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.waitForRemovals(OperationContextImpl.java:498)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.handleResult(AbstractOperationContext.java:1369)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:1328)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1311)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.access$300(AbstractOperationContext.java:1185)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeResultHandlerPhase(AbstractOperationContext.java:767)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:644)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:370)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1329)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:493)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:387)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:349)
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:397)
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:366)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:299)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2020-02-24 15:20:30,975 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.client] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.controller.ParallelBootOperationStepHandler$2@54f56232 for operation {"operation" => "parallel-subsystem-boot","address" => []} at address [] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
2020-02-24 15:20:35,977 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractAddStepHandler$1@4108480d for operation {"operation" => "add","host" => "localhost","port" => 25,"address" => [("socket-binding-group" => "standard-sockets"),("remote-destination-outbound-socket-binding" => "mail-smtp")],"source-interface" => undefined,"source-port" => undefined,"fixed-source-port" => undefined} at address [
    ("socket-binding-group" => "standard-sockets"),
    ("remote-destination-outbound-socket-binding" => "mail-smtp")
] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.waitForRemovals(OperationContextImpl.java:498)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.handleResult(AbstractOperationContext.java:1369)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:1328)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1311)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.access$300(AbstractOperationContext.java:1185)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeResultHandlerPhase(AbstractOperationContext.java:767)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:644)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:370)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1329)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:493)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:387)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:349)
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:397)
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:366)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:299)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2020-02-24 15:20:35,979 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.client] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractAddStepHandler$1@4108480d for operation {"operation" => "add","host" => "localhost","port" => 25,"address" => [("socket-binding-group" => "standard-sockets"),("remote-destination-outbound-socket-binding" => "mail-smtp")],"source-interface" => undefined,"source-port" => undefined,"fixed-source-port" => undefined} at address [
    ("socket-binding-group" => "standard-sockets"),
    ("remote-destination-outbound-socket-binding" => "mail-smtp")
] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
2020-02-24 15:20:40,985 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractAddStepHandler$1@5152a494 for operation {"address" => [("socket-binding-group" => "standard-sockets"),("socket-binding" => "txn-status-manager")],"operation" => "add","port" => 4713,"interface" => undefined,"fixed-port" => undefined,"multicast-address" => undefined,"multicast-port" => undefined,"client-mappings" => undefined} at address [
    ("socket-binding-group" => "standard-sockets"),
    ("socket-binding" => "txn-status-manager")
] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.waitForRemovals(OperationContextImpl.java:498)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.handleResult(AbstractOperationContext.java:1369)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:1328)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1311)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.access$300(AbstractOperationContext.java:1185)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeResultHandlerPhase(AbstractOperationContext.java:767)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:644)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:370)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1329)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:493)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:387)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:349)
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:397)
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:366)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:299)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2020-02-24 15:20:40,986 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.client] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractAddStepHandler$1@5152a494 for operation {"address" => [("socket-binding-group" => "standard-sockets"),("socket-binding" => "txn-status-manager")],"operation" => "add","port" => 4713,"interface" => undefined,"fixed-port" => undefined,"multicast-address" => undefined,"multicast-port" => undefined,"client-mappings" => undefined} at address [
    ("socket-binding-group" => "standard-sockets"),
    ("socket-binding" => "txn-status-manager")
] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
2020-02-24 15:20:45,987 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractAddStepHandler$1@23fec571 for operation {"address" => [("socket-binding-group" => "standard-sockets"),("socket-binding" => "txn-recovery-environment")],"operation" => "add","port" => 4712,"interface" => undefined,"fixed-port" => undefined,"multicast-address" => undefined,"multicast-port" => undefined,"client-mappings" => undefined} at address [
    ("socket-binding-group" => "standard-sockets"),
    ("socket-binding" => "txn-recovery-environment")
] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.waitForRemovals(OperationContextImpl.java:498)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.handleResult(AbstractOperationContext.java:1369)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:1328)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1311)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.access$300(AbstractOperationContext.java:1185)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeResultHandlerPhase(AbstractOperationContext.java:767)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:644)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:370)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1329)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:493)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:387)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:349)
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:397)
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:366)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:299)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Thanks in advance